# Integration problem, stuck at this.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, parametric

Here's the parametric equations:

$x = \sin (t)$
$y = \sin (2t)$

$ 0 \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2}$

(1) How would I find the area of the region bounded by the curve and the x axis.
(2) Volume of the solid formed when rotated $2\pi$ radians about x axis.

Comment: You can rewrite the curve as $y = 2x \sqrt{1-x^2}, x \in [0, 1]$ isn't it?

Comment: Note that $y=\sin(2t) = 2\sin(t)\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)^2 + \cos(t)^2 = 1$. From that you can express $y = f(x)$ and recover @LiChunMin expression.

Comment: Solved the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while, but solved. Was stuck in the integration part to be specific.

[image: method]

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the ordinary formulas for the area and the volume are $\int^b_a y \ dx$ and $\pi\int^b_a y^2 \ dx$.

For parametric equations, you replace $y$ with $y(t)$, $dx$ with $x'(t)dt$, and the limits of integration with the corresponding $t$ values, just as using the substitution rule for definite integrals.